# Disable GSM programmatically

Tags: android

In my app I would like to turn off GSM for short while to stop sms  from sending. My first thought was to programmatically turn airplane mode on but soon Ive learned that you cannot do that since android 4.4 or so. I tried to find some order method of doing it but i cant find anything. Is it simply because it cannot be done nowdays? Is it impossible to do?

Comment: what about GCM `unregister` method

Comment: I can imagine several kinds of malware making good use of this if it was possible.

Comment: Only if your application is a system application. If your phone is rooted, then you can install it on the system applications and have permissions to do that.